# Aggregate JSON object's own key value attributes in Athena using OpenX SerDe

Tags: sql, json, hive, presto, amazon-athena

I have a JSON structure that looks similar to this two example events:

Event 1

```
    {
      "event":{
             "type" : "FooBarEvent"
             "kv":{
                "key1":"value1",
                "key2":"value2",
                "3":"three",
                "d":"4"
             }
      }
    }
```

Event 2

```
    {
      "event":{
             "type" : "FooBarEvent"
             "kv":{
                "key1":"value1",
                "key2":"value2000",
                "e": "4"
             }
      }
    }
```

Note that I do not know upfront which keys and values are coming in and I'd like to aggregate(count) them. Output for the two events would look like follows:

```
+-----------+------+-----------+--------+
| EventType | Key  | Value     | Amount |
+-----------+------+-----------+--------+
| Foobar    | key1 | value1    | 2      |
+-----------+------+-----------+--------+
| Foobar    | key2 | value1    | 1      |
+-----------+------+-----------+--------+
| Foobar    | key2 | value2000 | 1      |
+-----------+------+-----------+--------+
| Foobar    | 3    | three     | 1      |
+-----------+------+-----------+--------+
| Foobar    | d    | 4         | 1      |
+-----------+------+-----------+--------+
| Foobar    | e    | 4         | 1      |
+-----------+------+-----------+--------+
```

Is there a way accomplishing this in Athena without changing the JSON structure? How Do I map and flatten/query the structure best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello it should work using `UNNEST` functionality and casting the `kv` to a map. The following query should work assuming your data is stored in a table called json_data

```
with data_formated as
(
    select *
    ,json_extract_scalar(json_field,'$.event.type') event_type
    ,cast(json_extract(json_field,'$.event.kv') as map(varchar,varchar)) key_value
    from json_data
)
,unnesting_data as
(
    select *
    from data_formated
    cross join unnest(key_value) as t (k,v)
)
select event_type,k,v,count(1) amount
from unnesting_data
group by 1,2,3
order by 1,2,3;
```